# c# unplug the usb when saving data to it, how to handle this exception

Tags: c#, exception, usbserial

I have a c# program saving data to a usb drive, but if the usb is unplugged, there will be a crash. Is there any good way to handle this exception?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the crash/exception and can you provide the code where you are writing to the drive when the exception occurs?

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using to write will likely raise an exception which you should be able to capture and respond to accordingly using a try/catch block.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx